# Upload large XML data to WCF service without streaming

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, large-data

I am writing a wcf service to receive XML data in request which contains some log info. As i am processing a large amount of data i don't want to have all those xml data in memory after receiving at the server side to avoid large memory consumption and possibly a timeout on processing.

I dont want to use Streaming as xml size is not more than 2 MB. So is there any other way to receive such large data through service reliably without affecting memory.

and this MSDN mentions not to use streaming for my situation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

and it says to use packets:

```
For data that does not have these constraints, it is typically better to send sequences of messages within the scope of a session than one large message. For more information, see the "Streaming Data" section later in this topic.
```

but i dont get clear idea on how to implement.

I was able to get example only on streaming but not on sending data in small chunks without streaming. any links or idea to implement that in wcf?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are worried about loading a < 2MB file into memory? I'm not sure the `large-data` tag is appropriate here.

Comment: I'm quite confused about your question. Why are you against streaming? If your system really has so little memory that 2MB will be problem and you need read the xml into memory in chunks then you should use streaming that is what it is for.